# May be time for new kettle. Advantages of Stainless Steel?

Tags: boil-kettle, stainless

I've had the same 10G aluminum BK since I started AG brewing, about 4 years and 70 batches.  I recently left my copper IC in it for a few months and think I may have corroded the aluminum, so it may be replacement time.  I am considering stainless steel, but want to know any advantages it brings for just about double the price of aluminum.  I should mention that I brew in a bag in this vessel (my bag was sewn custom for this kettle).  I also have a step-drill (weldless) installed brewmometer and valve installed in the kettle.

-What are the advantages/disadvantages of SS vs. aluminum?
-Will I compromise the stainless coating by using a step drill/pilot hole for the valve and thermometer fittings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main advantage with SS is that it is quite inert - had you had a stainless kettle, the corrosion problem you experienced with the immersion chiller wouldn't have happened.

Since it's happened once, it's quite likely to happen again, meaning you'd end up buying 2 new aluminum kettles (for a total of 3.) So in the long run stainless will work out cheaper.

You won't compromise the passive oxide layer from boring holes, it forms naturally in contact with oxygen - just be sure to clean the part well after making a hole. I drilled many holes in my 3 SS kettles (see my avatar) and I have had no problem in 3 years (although I used a step bit to make only the pilot hole for the conduit punch, which makes a much cleaner hole.)

If you have the money, go with stainless, you won't regret it.